# What is the determinant of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Can anyone help me with the determinant of this matrix?

$
\mathbf{J}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{x_{1}}{y_{1}} & \frac{x_{1}}{y_{2}} & \frac{x_{1}}{y_{3}} & \cdots & \frac{x_{1}}{y_{d-1}} & \frac{x_{1}}{y_{d}}\\
\frac{x_{2}}{y_{1}} & \frac{x_{2}}{y_{2}} & \frac{x_{2}}{y_{3}} & \cdots & \frac{x_{2}}{y_{d-1}} & \frac{-x_{2}}{1-y_{d}}\\
\frac{x_{3}}{y_{1}} & \frac{x_{3}}{y_{2}} & \frac{x_{3}}{y_{3}} &  & \frac{-x_{3}}{1-y_{d-1}} & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}} & 0 & \vdots\\
\frac{x_{d-1}}{y_{1}} & \frac{x_{d-1}}{y_{2}} & \frac{-x_{d-1}}{1-y_{3}} & \cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}} & 0 & 0\\
\frac{x_{d}}{y_{1}} & \frac{-x_{d}}{1-y_{2}} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$

It must be simple due to the triangular structure but I don't get it....

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, what is the determinant of the $2\times 2$ case? The $3\times 3$ case?

Comment: Are you sure that the second last entry of the third row says $\frac{-x_3}{1-y_2}$, and not $\frac{-x_3}{1-y_{d-2}}$?

Comment: Double check your matrix entries, the subscripts seem incorrect.

Comment: I just fixed all indices, good point!

Comment: You can pull a factor of $x_i$ out of the $i$th row and a factor of ${1\over y_i}$ out of the $i$th column, and get a matrix with at most one element $\neq0,1$ in each row and column.

Comment: @saulspatz : unfortunately we can't for the $y_i$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Why not?  That's where you get the one element that isn't $0$ or $1$.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @saulspatz You are right in fact. I was embarassed by the fact that there are exceptional entries where the denominator is $1-y_i$ instead of $y_i$ but in fact those entries will become $y_i/(1-y_1)$, that's all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints :**

A first step : factorization of $J$ (see the remark by @saulspatz) :

$$J=diag(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{d-1},x_d) \times K \times diag(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_{d-1},y_d)$$

where $K$ is a matrix with non-zero entries at the same place as in $J$ but with every $x_k/y_k$ replaced by $1$ and every $-x_k/(1-y_k)$ replaced by $-y_k/(1-y_k)$.

Let us now define matrix $R$ as the "reversal" matrix with entries $0$ except on the anti-diagonal where $R_{k,n-k}=1$.

Please note that $\det(R)=(-1)^{n-1}$.

$H:=KR$ has the same columns as $K$ but in a reversed order, making it a so-called "upper Hessenberg matrix" (that can be described as a upper triangular to which a lower diagonal has been added) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).

It remains now to compute $\det(H)$, using one of the algorithms for the computation of the determinant of a Hessenberg matrix : see (journal.pmf.ni.ac.rs/filomat/index.php/filomat/article/download/4595/2309) or (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3206872).