# Determinant of a special diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a matrix of:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b  & b & \cdots & b \cr
-1 & 1 & 0 & \ddots & \vdots \cr
0 & -1 & 1 & \ddots & \vdots \cr
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1 \cr
\end{bmatrix}_{N \times N}
$$
To calculate the determinant I followed the most general approach:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_A &= a \cdot \text{det}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \cr
    -1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & \vdots \cr
    0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots & \vdots \cr
    0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & \vdots \cr
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots &\ddots & 1 \cr
\end{bmatrix}
 - b \cdot
\text{det} 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & \vdots \\
\vdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}  
+ b \cdot
\text{det} 
(A_{13}) + \cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
So the good news is the second matrix that I faced is a diagonal matrix consisting of either 1 or -1 on the diagonal. Actually, it's not a diagonal matrix but it's a diagonal matrix with non-zero off-diagonal values. I numerically calculate the determinant of such a matrix (up to size 100) and it seems that the determinant is no different from the determinant of a simple diagonal matrix:

$\text{det} A = \prod_{i=1}^{N}  A_{ii}$

I wonder if there's any proof for that.

Comment: For any upper triangular (or lower triangular) matrix the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the matrix is a particular upper Hessenberg so the closed form of its determinant in this case [should be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396772/evaluate-the-determinant-of-a-hessenberg-matrix) $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(a_k\prod_{i=1}^{k} y_i\prod_{i=k+1}^{n-1} x_i\right)$$

where $a_k = \begin{cases}a & k = 0 \\ b & k \geq 1\end{cases}$ and $x_i = y_i = 1$ for each $i$. It follows that the formulas simplifies to $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k = a + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k = a + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} b = a+(n-1)b$$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Seems really nice this way. I don't see the companion matrix according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) though. Aren't the $b$'s in wrong place? Pheraphs they are similar?

Comment: The form of $I-A$ is the form a companion matrix? @SassatelliGiulio