Has this determinant already been calculated?
I've encountered the following gnarly looking determinant that I'm having trouble calculating: $$\begin{vmatrix}
a_{k,1}&a_{k,2}&a_{k,3}&\cdots&a_{k,k-1}&b_k\\
a_{k-1,1}&a_{k-1,2}&a_{k-1,3}&\cdots&a_{k-1,k-1}&b_{k-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&0&\cdots&0&b_2\\
a_{1,1}&0&0&\cdots&0&b_1
 \end{vmatrix}.$$
Though, I should note that I did, in fact, figure out a way to calculate it via the following series of row operations: $$\{Γ_i\toΓ_i-a_{k-i+1,j}Γ_{k-j+1},i=1,2,...,k-j\}$$ for $j=1,2,...,k-1$, where before enacting the above series of type I row operations, an $a_{j,j}$ is factored out from the $k-j+1$-th row, and then the determinant should like the following:
$$a_{1,1}...a_{k-1,k-1}\begin{vmatrix}
0&0&0&\cdots&0&*\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&*\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&1&\cdots&0&\frac{b_3}{a_{3,3}}-\frac{a_{3,2}}{a_{2,2}a_{3,3}}b_2-\frac{a_{3,1}}{a_{1,1}a_{3,3}}b_1+\frac{a_{3,2}a_{2,1}}{a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}}b_1\\
0&1&0&\cdots&0&\frac{b_2}{a_{2,2}}-\frac{a_{2,1}}{a_{1,1}a_{2,2}}b_1\\
1&0&0&\cdots&0&\frac{b_1}{a_{1,1}}
 \end{vmatrix}.$$
Now, the desired quantity should accumulate at the top right corner, but this is quite the challenge, and any help would be much appreciated. Although, to save me some time I wanted to ask whether this determinant has already been calculated, and if so, could I be given a reference? Thank you in advance.

By cycling the columns one step to the right, you are basically asking about the determinant of a general Hessenberg matrix, if I understand your notation correctly.

@IzaakvanDongen I've literally never heard of the term Hessenberg matrix. Is this information useful?

The name of that matrix does not matter. Have you clicked on the link provided by @IzaakvanDongen ?  What technique to calculate its determinant comes to mind now?

@KurtG. I did click on the link, but wikipedia does not outline any method of calculating the determinant of a general Hessenberg matrix. Also, if I were to cycle the columns on step to the right, as pointed out by Izaak van Dongen, I neither end up with an upper Hessengberg matrix nor a lower Hessenberg matrix. So I still don't know how to proceed. See this reference https://planetmath.org/hessenbergmatrix.

Too long for a comment:
Your matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k,1}&a_{k,2}&a_{k,3}&\cdots&a_{k,k-1}&b_k\\
a_{k-1,1}&a_{k-1,2}&a_{k-1,3}&\cdots&a_{k-1,k-1}&b_{k-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&0&\cdots&0&b_2\\
a_{1,1}&0&0&\cdots&0&b_1
 \end{pmatrix}
becomes a Hessenberg matrix by permuting columns:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{k,k-1}&a_{k,k-2}&\cdots&a_{k,2}&a_{k,1}&b_k\\
a_{k-1,k-1}&a_{k-1,k-2}&\cdots &a_{k-1,2} &a_{k-1,1}&b_{k-1}\\
0&a_{k-2,k-2}& \ddots &\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&a_{2,2}&a_{2,1}&b_2\\
0&0&\cdots&0&a_{1,1}&b_1
 \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Now try to calculate the determinant by developing w.r.t. to the first column
or the last row.

Stupid me finally sees it now, thank you. However, when commuting any two columns (or rows) a negative sign appears before the determinant, so after all these permutations, what am I left with, regarding the negative signs?

Of course.  You have to keep track of all those sign changes. Also when you develop by that row or column. I don't know how much time we spend on finding sign errors. Perhaps 50% ?

Upon further thinking, I now know how to collect all negative signs via the necessary column commutations, depending on the parity of $k$. I'll accept your answer, since yours is much clearer and precise than Izaak's, because I assumed he was talking about permuting every column. But, apparently the last column need not be permuted. Take care, kind stranger.

Thanks. But the credit should go to @IzaakvanDongen who quickly gave the essential hint. Please post the determinant once you have it.

What do you mean by 'post the determinant'? Do you mean 'post the closed form of the determinant'?

Yes. $\phantom{.}$

Well, I think it'd be a simpler endeavor, if someone had already found the closed form of the determinant of a general lower Hessenberg matrix. Wouldn't you agree?

How boring. $\phantom{.}$ Start with Hessenberg matrices of size $3\times 3$ and increase their size in steps. Maybe you see a pattern. Then use induction.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is nothing to discuss. Homework time.

I know, it's just that the system says to avoid extended discussions in comments.

I just found online the general recurrence formula. In this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396772/evaluate-the-determinant-of-a-hessenberg-matrix the user @SGJ provided a link to a paper from 2003 by Cahill et al. So end of homework time.

I found that too about 30 minutes ago and almost linked to it. But then I realized that their Hessenberg matrix has a lot more zeroes than yours. But in fact, in the answer there from SGJ it looks like that is it. I would probably verify it before using it. :)

Well, since Cahill provided a proof of the general recurrence formula, there's no need for verification. So I'll just reference his paper.
